# XMage alternative to draft Magic the Gathering online?

Tags: magic-the-gathering, mtg-arena, mtg-drafting

I'm getting back into Magic the Gathering at the start of Innistrad Midnight Hunt. I used to use XMage for drafts online, but while the program looks alive and well, it doesn't seem like there are any active players drafting on it. Is there a newer alternative that players have moved to?

I checked out Arena and grinding 10,000 gold for every draft or paying $10 per draft are off the table for me.

Answer (score 4):

> Is there a newer alternative that players have moved to?

Arena; that may not be the answer you want to hear, but it *is* where the players are.

If you're reasonable at drafting (e.g. a 50% win rate or higher), it's much less than 10k gold per draft because of the gem rewards; 4-3 in a Bo1 draft is 1400 gems, which is close enough to the 1500 gems you need.

Comment: Thx for the response. A smaller community is fine, XMage was always minuscule compared to MTGO, but there were usually 2 drafts running at a time of the newest set which was great. For the Arena grind, assuming a free draft is won with gems 50% of the time, I'd still need to grind 7500 gold per draft, which is like 40 games I don't want to play.

Comment: @Koyok *For the Arena grind, assuming a free draft is won with gems 50% of the time, I'd still need to grind 7500 gold per draft* How did you get this number? The idea is you grind for one draft, then "go infinite" by enough matches. Last I saw, going 6-3 in a BO1 draft returns more than the cost of entry; 5-3 is also sufficient in conjunction with daily quests.

Comment: @Koyok If you're good enough at drafting it takes a 5/3 result on the Best-Of-One Premier Drafts(1600 gem reward) or 3/0 on every other the Best-Of-Three Traditional Drafts(3000 gem reward) to earn your 1500 gem entry back and go straight into the next one. Doing better on Premier (up to 7/3 before you stop earning more prizes) or getting a win or two on the off traditional drafts give you some cushion if you fail to win enough on occasion.

Comment: @Allure 5 wins before 3 losses on premier BO1 gives 1600 gems, paying the 1500 gem cost of your next draft.

Comment: @Koyok usually when a set comes out, wizards only unlocks premier drafts. I'd advise you to wait a few more days/weeks until quick drafts are available. They cost 750Gems/5000Gold.

Comment: @bautista Ty, if it drops to 5000 that's much better. I'll give Arenas a shot a shot, but I still haven't earned my first 10,000 gold from dailies since posting.

Answer (score 1):

#### There are programs that allow you to draft against a computer.

Forge is a fan-created program that lets you play Magic the Gathering games against an AI opponent. One of the modes you can do so in is Drafting, and after the draft is over, you'll be able to play against the AI drafted decks.

Additionally, there's the website draftsim.com. it also lets you draft against an AI, though in this case I believe that the AI's card selection is influenced by how often a card is picked by previous players. Unlike Forge, however, there isn't any option to actually play the decks you've drafted.

Answer (score -1):

If you're interested in drafting old sets on XMage this Discord server might interest you: https://discord.gg/YE59Eaj They are the XMage Draft Historical Society and they run multiple drafts every week of old Magic sets.